# Transform Swagger parameter names to Postman variables on import

Tags: swagger, postman, openapi

I have a set of Swagger file that defines the parameters in the usual manner. For instance:

```
parameters:
      - $ref: '#/parameters/authorization'
...  
parameters:  
  authorization:
    name: Authorization
    description: ''
    required: true
    type: string
    in: header
```

Upon importing these file into Postman, the Postman collection is correctly created, however I'd like the Postman variable for the "Authorization" parameter to be "AUTH_TOKEN" instead of "Authorization" (for instance).

Effectively, I want to declare a field (ideally in the swagger file?) that says "when exported to Postman, used the value AUTH_TOKEN as the variable name, instead of the default 'name' of "Authorization").

It seemed like x-postman-meta in the swagger might help with, but didn't find any info on this property outside of the GH issue on here saying it might help.

Anyhow - how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I've found a way to do this, although it doesn't feel good from a OpenAPI/Swagger perspective.  What I found is you can add a "default" property with your variable name e.g.

```
    {
      "in": "header",
      "name": "Authorization",
      "description": "The bearer token in the format: Bearer {token}",
      "required": true,
      "type": "string",
      "default": "Bearer {{token}}"
    }
```

This feels bad because what the default property actually is for:

> Use the default keyword in the parameter schema to specify the default value for
>   an optional parameter. The default value is the one that the server uses if the
>   client does not supply the parameter value in the request. The value type must
>   be the same as the parameter’s data type.

So this wouldn't work if you had a integer type that you wanted to fill with a variable.  Additionally, from a documentation standpoint it's plain wrong, the server requires this parameter to be provided by the client, it can't also have a default value, that's contradictory.  Would be interested in a more "feel-good" solution.

Reference:
https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-parameters/